# Extract unmatched string in python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I have two strings s and s2

```
s = "catwalksonterrace9_ontheweekend_at7am"
s2= "catwalksonterrace$no_ontheweekend_at.*"
```

I need to compare two strings and extract the unmatched portions that are
`$no = 9` and `.* = 7am` from both the strings in Python. I am new to python how would I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at difflib, it's awesome, made to do exactly what you want :)
https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html

```
import difflib
d = difflib.Differ()
diffs = []
in_diff = False
for c in d.compare(s, s2):
    if not in_diff and (c.startswith("+") or c.startswith("-")):
        diffs.append(["", ""])
        in_diff = True
    if c.startswith("+"):
        diffs[-1][0] += c.replace("+ ", "")
    elif c.startswith("-"):
        diffs[-1][1] += c.replace("- ", "")
    else:
        in_diff = False
print(diffs)
```

This creates a list of lists, where first value of each sublist is diff on line 1, and seocnd value is diff on line 2

Output will be:

```
[['$no', '9'], ['.*', '7am']]
```

You can then loop through that, printing out as requested:

```
for diff in diffs:
    print(diff[0], "=", diff[1])
```

Comment: it will give `<generator object Differ.compare ...` but not the final strings

Comment: Try doing list() on the result

Comment: while it is your job, here it is `['  c', '  a', '  t', '  w', '  a', '  l', '  k', '  s', '  o', '  n', '  t', '  e', '  r', '  r', '  a', '  c', '  e', '- 9', '+ $', '+ n', '+ o', '  _', '  o', '  n', '  t', '  h', '  e', '  w', '  e', '  e', '  k', '  e', '  n', '  d', '  _', '  a', '  t', '+ .', '+ *', '- 7', '- a', '- m']`

Comment: maor10, @RomanPerekhrest is just trying to help you improve your answer. It won't kill you to add details that would make your answer more useful than just "here is a totally new library that does what you want, take it and go".

Comment: @maor10, the point is that I'm testing your approach and it does not give the expected result *$no =9 and .*=7am* as claimed in the question. I think that the upvote was too hasty

Comment: I'll edit the answer to achieve the exact result, but I thought it better to provide the beginning, and let the "asker" finish it himself, so this isn't simply a question of copy-paste; from my understanding, this site isn't supposed to be "Write some code for me"

Answer (score 0):

With [***difflib.unified_diff()***](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html?highlight=difflib#difflib.unified_diff) function:

```
import difflib, itertools

s1 = "catwalksonterrace9_ontheweekend_at7am"
s2 = "catwalksonterrace$no_ontheweekend_at.*"

result = []
for i in itertools.islice(difflib.unified_diff(s1, s2, lineterm=''), 2, None):
    if i.startswith('@@'):    # diff control line
        result.append(['',''])
    elif i.startswith('-'):   # line unique to sequence 1
        result[-1][0] += i[1:]
    elif i.startswith('+'):   # line unique to sequence 2
        result[-1][1] += i[1:]

print(result)
```

The output:

```
[['9', '$no'], ['7am', '.*']]
```

---

Each sublist in the resulting `result` list contains a pair of "*old*" and "*new*" value (i.e. `[<old>, <new>]`)